# Storing the Unique ID of the Document in Web

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I need to save or store the current document unique or universal ID in web lotus notes application. I tried using `@Text(@DocumentUniqueID)` but it doesn't work and as I researched about it, it wouldn't really work. Is there another way? Currently I am opening a new form through open agent in web then I need to store the unique id so they would be related. I am not sure if this question is already answered but I can't find the answer.. I need to ask since I have a deadline..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `WebQuerySave` event of your form to set the Universal ID.

Say you create an agent `aSetUNID` and call it from `WebQuerySave`

```
@Command([ToolsRunMacro]; "aSetUNID");
```

In your agent `aSetUNID` you would write something like this:

```
Dims s as New NotesSession
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Set doc = s.DocumentContext
Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("DocUNID_Field", doc.UniversalID)
```

Comment: Hi Naveen,, it is working fine cool.. Thanks a lot for your help.. though I already tried and applied that.. though I used that through the open agent.. It was not working then probably the context being taken is not the current document since it gives another different unique id.. Thanks a lot for your help naveen..

Answer (score 1):

One way to make them related is to make the other document response to main document. You can do it by creating the new document this way:

```
?OpenForm&ParentUNID=<unid>
```

Comment: Hi Panu, Thanks a lot.. actually it is not a response document but also how would I apply that if I can't get the Unique ID of the document? the "<unid>" means the exact document unique id right? Thanks a lot for helping Panu

Comment: One way to get the UnID is in Naveen's answers as you've seen. `@Text(@DocumentUniqueID)` should also work.

Comment: Yeah,, thanks Panu, though for the @Text(@DocumentUniqueID).. it doesn't work on web.. Thanks though.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes it does but anyway looks like you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK a new document in Notes (read: not saved yet) does not have a Universal ID. The document only gets its Universal ID once saved for the first time. On the web interface with Domino this is a little different: you are in fact accessing a temporary document with a temporary universal ID, which the document receives while it is new. When saved the id will be (or should be) changed. So the agent as described elsewhere could indeed do what you want, but that's not the recommended way.

Unless I'm terribly mistaken you have to create an agent that is triggered on When documents are created or modified. That agent should visit the documents without the field you need, in order to add it.

Comment: Hi Sjef, yes indeed I get what you meant since I also searched why it was not working and got the same answer. Do you mean the method naveen showed is not recommended? why?.. Thanks a lot for helping sjef.. Is there a way for an agent to run when there is created or modified document? or you meant I'll create a scheduled agent then check? anyways I get what you mean.. Thanks.. right now I applied what naveen shared but if there is something wrong I can update.. thanks

Comment: That's indeed what I implied, but since I didn't do some tests myself to prove my statement it's still only a hypothesis. And indeed I intended to suggest a scheduled agent, triggered on When documents are created or modified. It might be triggered too often, so you could think of using a view that contains all documents with a Select Form="X" & UniqueID=""